# Migration to Content Builder from Classic Content

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, dataextensions, triggered-send, content-builder

I mainly use an AMPScript email to create&send emails using Triggered Send. The AMPScript email (script) loads the required information from content html files and values from the Data Extensions depending on the REST API request sent to the associated Triggered Send.

I have a lot of content html files and not sure where to start to migrate all this stuff. I have a main html content that works as a template. I have different footers depending on different conditions. And different content depending on the purpose of the emails. Different languages as well.

For the classic content tool I was using a [php library](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-PHP) to update contents and data extensions from our server. Is there anything similar to that library in Content Builder?.  I have barely reviewed the Content Builder documentation and seems there are a [tool](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/blocksdk)

I understood the Triggered Sends still will be valid after reconfigure them to use the new email from Content Builder, right?. Is there a way to do it in an automated way, I mean, not use the graphical interface?

Thanks for any insights.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the migrations utilities will not convert `ContentArea(<classicId>)` into `ContentBlockById(contentBuilderId)`. Here are the steps I would follow to migrate your existing emails:

1. Use the content builder migration utility to migrate all your referenced HTML content areas. This will create CB HTML blocks.
2. Copy paste the content of your email into a new CB HTML paste email.
3. Remap your references by replacing your classic `ContentArea(<classicId>)` into `ContentBlockById(contentBuilderId)`
4. Remap your triggered send to the new CB email ID

If you want to do any of the CB content creation programmatically you can refer to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/content-api.htm).